# What are the categories of IND and PRO schemes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-stacks

below is a [mathexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4875735/what-are-the-categories-of-ind-and-pro-schemes?noredirect=1#comment10397819_4875735) with no answers so I drop it here.

*I have some difficulties to figure out what the category of IND-schemes and PRO-schemes are, in particualer the relations with others categories in algebraic geometry.
Are they full subcategory of algebraic stacks? Are they full subcategory of algebraic spaces? Neither?*